How to dynamically return values horizontally in Google Sheets
Say I have a column like this:



user
item




User1
Item1


User1
Item2


User1
Item3


User1
Item4


User1
Item5


User2
Item1


User3
Item1



How can I return them like this in a filter/lookup formula:



user









User1
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
Item5


User2
Item1






User3
Item1







I am familiar with regular vlookup and filter formulas but didn't find a way to achieve this.
For example, I tried =UNIQUE(C2:C) and =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D2:D, C2:C = G2:G))) but it only works if I don't have arrayformula and instead drag the formula down manually... What I want is for this to work automatically for all new data so I don't have to manually drag the formula down for each row.
Here is a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/g23fzJgPbv4O
Here is a test spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NyJZpBe-Btg1JI6DTwWmVcYgbBpC2m2QcxaWVqNW9EI

With your example table present at the top-left of the sheet, you can try: =map(unique(A2:A8),lambda(user,{user,transpose(filter(B2:B8,A2:A8=user))}))

hiiii, i saw that you haven't answered any questions since july, so i made a follow-up post about a question related to your formula, but feel free to lmk if you still see this, any help would be greatly appreciated! but no worries if you see this late, take care and stay safe!
